# Haskell, possible indentation error that I can't get rid of

Tags: haskell, indentation

I have a problem and cannot find out what it is. I have reindented again over and over, but cannot find the solution. Is there something else this can be dependent on?

Code:

```
type Triple = (Prime, Quot, Gen)

correctness :: Triple -> Bool
correctness (p,q,g) = prime && pLength && qLength && divisor && orderq
           where prime   = probablyPrime n 5
                 qLength = q < 2^1024
                 pLength = p < 2^160
                 divisor = (p-1 `mod` q) == 0
                 orderq  = (g^q mod p == 1) && (g > 1)
```

Error Message (line 94 corresponds to "correctness :: Triple -> Bool"):

```
crypt.hs:94:0: parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

EDIT: I solved the problem. The problem was a syntax error in an above function. I had `otherwise m_ify m*2` instead of `otherwise = m_ify m*2`

Comment: Can you provide some more code? It seems like the misstake happend long before.

Comment: FWIW, just because it says "possibly incorrect indentation" doesn't mean that it's an indentation issue.  It's just drawing attention to the fact that some parse errors can be indentation errors.  Just doublecheck your syntax in the few lines surrounding the line it's complaining about.

Comment: To follow up luqui's comment, check that you closed all parens before line 94.

Comment: I think you want `(p-1) \`mod\` q == 0` in penultimate line.

Comment: sorry, n should be q. but that did not solved the issue. I realized however that it was correct that the error was far up.

Answer (score 1):

Worksforme, jumps right into the type errors.

Is line 92 the

```
type Triple = (Prime, Quot, Gen)
```

line, or did you move that from somewhere else?  Sometimes errors can show up with a line number later than where they actually occur.  I would check for mismatched parentheses above line 92 (probably nearby).

And on some occasions an invisible unicode character seems to sneak into my code.  Retyping has occasionally worked.

Answer (score 1):

You might just need to add backticks around the `mod` in the final line. This wouldn't cause the indentation error you report, but the following compiles for me:

```
n = undefined
probablyPrime = undefined
type Prime = Int
type Quot = Int
type Gen = Int

type Triple = (Prime, Quot, Gen)

correctness :: Triple -> Bool
correctness (p,q,g) = prime && pLength && qLength && divisor && orderq
           where prime   = probablyPrime n 5
                 qLength = q < 2^1024
                 pLength = p < 2^160
                 divisor = (p-1 `mod` q) == 0
                 orderq  = (g^q `mod` p == 1) && (g > 1)
```

The only change here (apart from the first five lines) is in the last line.

Comment: I missed the backtick. I guess GHC had not come that far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
type Triple = (Prime, Quot, Gen)

correctness :: Triple -> Bool
correctness (p,q,g) = prime && pLength && qLength && divisor && orderq
           where 
              prime   = probablyPrime n 5
              qLength = q < 2^1024
              pLength = p < 2^160
              divisor = (p-1 `mod` q) == 0
              orderq  = (g^q mod p == 1) && (g > 1)
```

Read - http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html - 9.3 Layout